# How to analyze core dump

Tags: ubuntu, stack-dump

After application[rtorrent] crashed, it produced `core` file, 250MB.

```
Caught Segmentation fault, dumping stack:B] [Port: 58940][U 0/0] [D 0/10] [H 1/32] [S 72/75/768] [F 0/128]
Stack dump not enabled.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What I need is to analyze and see the stack trace, to have clue why rtorrent is crashing so often.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`gdb`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) should be able to analyse the core:

```
gdb /path/to/binary/rtorrent /path/to/coredump/rtorrent.core
```

type `where` to see stack trace.

To see more: compile rtorrent with debug symbols, run, wait crash and analyse dump with gdb (in this case you can see exact place where crash occurs).

**UPD** One note, rtorrent is build on top of libtorrent as I know, so, you have to rebuild both library and application with debug symbols in order to get full information.